# Structured UAT approaches

Tags: testing, project-management, uat

As a developer I often release different versions of applications that I want tested by users to identify bugs and to confirm requirements are being met.

I give the users a rough idea of what I have changed or new features that need testing, but this seems a bit slap-dash and not very well strucutured.

I'd like to know what approaches or procedures others take when asking for UAT during iterative development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I find that writing test scripts is increadibly time consuming, often longer than the time taken to put the fix into place.  With the large volume of work we do here we just don't have the time to create effective testing scripts.

With our changes we push the testing through two levels, applicaiton support and business acceptance.  It is our hope that with a technical approach and a business approach that most of the aspects of the change will be tested.  To let them know what they should test we attach a list of actions that have been effected by the change (Adding a product, Removing a product, Editing a product).

This coupled with a strong unit testing approach is the best approach to a high volume environment in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

User Stories or Use Cases might be what you are looking for, how did you decide on the change in the first place and how did you specify it. If you write up a little story, or bigger a actual structured use case you can use it as the specification for your change and then the users can test against that story to see whether the implementation matches the description.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I create a script in excel with each feature list and an "Expected Result" and "Actual Result" column, with the Expected Result column filled out with what should transpire.  For my own use I include a column that is the id of the item.  This corresponds with the Task Id from Team System or the WSB from the project plan created

Answer (score 0):

You're seeking an efficient and effective way to conduct UAT in a structured manner.  I highly recommend using a pairwise or combinatorial test design approach.  I have used this approach in more than 2 dozen proof of concept projects and found that, as compared to traditional methods of identifying test cases manually, this approach consistently leads to dramatically more defects being found per tester hour.  In fact, on average, as reported in a recent IEEE Computer [article](http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=hexawise.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcsrc.nist.gov%2Fgroups%2FSNS%2Facts%2Fdocuments%2Fkuhn-kacker-lei-hunter09.pdf) I co-wrote, we found 2.4 X as many defects per tester hour *on average*.

The approach is described in the video [here](http://hexawise.com/intro_movie).  Apologies if this appears to be an "use my tool" plug.  I don't mean it to be.  It is the **approach** that will deliver dramatic benefits, not the specific tool you choose to use to design your tests.  James Bach also offers a free tool called AllPairs on his satisfice.com site.  My point is that using any such tool will generate dramatically superior results because these tools are designed to generate maximum coverage in a minimum number of tests.  They avoid repetition; in addition, they automatically identify and close potential gaps in coverage that manual test case identification methods will fail to close.

While it might be counter-intuitive that a tool like Hexawise would be able to identify (in seconds) the UAT test cases that should be run better than testers would be able to identify and document (in days), it is nevertheless true.  Try it for yourself.  Have one UAT tester on your team execute 20 end-to-end "black box" or "gray box" tests that are created with Hexawise and have other testers test what they usually would.  I would bet good money that the tester executing the 20 Hexawise tests would find many more defects per tester hour (and would find "important" as well as "unimportant" defects).

It is a shame that these kinds of methods aren't much better known in the testing community outside of a relatively sophisticated group of testers who take the time to read books like Lee Copeland's book on test design methods.  Pairwise and combinatorial methods work consistently, they deliver enormous improvements in efficiency and effectiveness, and they are quite easy for testing teams to start using immediately.

Justin (Founder of Hexawise)